# Gas fireplace is connected to the thermostat. Is there a way to disconnect?

Tags: heating, furnace, fireplace

New home has a gas fireplace that that we believe is connected to our thermostat. The fire will turn on/off continuously. Is there a way to disconnect it so we can just have the fireplace ON continuously when we want to use it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I imagine that's not nice to your heating bill @JordanScantlen. There's no enough information to answer your question well. I'm sure there's a way to disconnect it and install a separate switch so you can turn it off and on at well, how that would be done depends on your setup. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: If your home is brand new call and discuss this with the builder, they know what they installed and how it should operate.   A few observations: normally when this is done it's not the same thermostat as your heating/furnace, generally when a fireplace stat is installed it's a separate thermostat.  It's also possible if this is new that something isn't installed correctly your fire is cutting off due to an over temp safety feature.  In any case, unless the cycling is being caused by a safty device then yes it can be changed.  Please include model numbers and/or photos the fireplace controls.

Comment: Is there any pattern to it turning off and on? Something like it running for 5 minutes and off 5 minutes, or is it inconsistent/random and will be on and off in a matter of seconds?  If it's really inconsistent/random then it might just be a loose wire nut. Does it seem to want to keep the room a certain temperature? There might be a wireless thermostat that controls the fireplace. What makes you think it is connected to the main thermostat, does it turn on and off with your furnace, or maybe feel like it's turning off only when it gets the room warm and back on when cold?

Comment: Yeah, before you go tearing into the system, be sure you understand how it was intended to be used. It probably has its own thermostat or other control, which may offer some nice features.

Comment: `we believe is connected to our thermostat` what makes you believe that?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this a couple of times.  If your situation is the same as mine, here is what's happening:  The fireplace operates on extremely low voltage. Because of this, it doesn't require much outside influence to induce a voltage in the stat wire to open the gas valve on the fireplace. If when the fireplace was installed, the installers ran the stat wire through the same drilled holes with line voltage circuitry wires, this is how it happens. Someone turns on a chandelier of the refrigerator starts. Those circuit wires experience a significant up tick in current flow.  That current induces an induction field all around the cable. If the stat wire falls within that field, the fireplace starts. It is like a mini transformer.

Comment: Disconnect the existing stat wire and in its place install a simple on/off switch.